# Merge statement and trigger SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, triggers

I have a merge statement supposed to execute a trigger multiple times.

I first thought my trigger wasn't executing, but with some research I found that triggers are only triggered once per statement (a trigger being one statement).

But all the posts out there are old and I thought that there might be a simple way now to make my trigger execute multiple times.

So is there anything I can add to my trigger or my merge statement to make my trigger do so?

Thanks

**TRIGGER**

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[Sofi_TERA_Trigger]
   ON [dbo].[ZZ]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Statut LIKE '%CLOT%' OR inserted.Statut LIKE '%CLTT%' OR inserted.Statut LIKE '%CONF%')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Id int;
            DECLARE @Matricule varchar(10);
            DECLARE @IdAction int;
            DECLARE @NumeroOF int; 
            SELECT @NumeroOF = inserted.Ordre from inserted;

            DECLARE OF_CURSOR CURSOR
                LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
            FOR
            SELECT Id,Log.Matricule,IdAction from Log inner join (select max(Id) as maxID,Matricule from LOG where Log.NumeroOF = @NumeroOF group by Matricule) maxID 
            on maxID.maxID = Log.Id where Log.NumeroOF = @NumeroOF;

            OPEN OF_CURSOR
            FETCH NEXT FROM OF_CURSOR INTO @Id,@Matricule,@IdAction
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF @IdAction!=13
                    BEGIN
                        IF @IdAction<=2
                        BEGIN
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,13,GETDATE(),1);
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,2,GETDATE(),1);
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,13,GETDATE(),1);
                        END
                    END              
                FETCH NEXT FROM OF_CURSOR INTO @Id,@Matricule,@IdAction
            END

            CLOSE OF_CURSOR;
            DEALLOCATE OF_CURSOR;
    END 
END
```

**MERGE STATEMENT**

```
Merge ZZ AS TARGET USING ZZTemp AS SOURCE 
ON (Target.Operation=Source.Operation AND Target.Ordre=Source.Ordre) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.DateTERA=SOURCE.DateTERA, TARGET.MatTERA=SOURCE.MatTERA, TARGET.MatTERC=SOURCE.MatTERC 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN                       
INSERT(Operation,Ordre,ElementOTP,Article,DesignationOF,PosteTravail,ValeurTemps,DHT,Statut,StatutOF,TexteActivite,DateTERA,MatTERA,MatTERC,StatutMat)                                  
VALUES(SOURCE.Operation,SOURCE.Ordre,SOURCE.ElementOTP,SOURCE.Article,SOURCE.DesignationOF,SOURCE.PosteTravail,SOURCE.ValeurTemps,SOURCE.DHT,
SOURCE.Statut,SOURCE.StatutOF,SOURCE.TexteActivite,SOURCE.DateTERA,SOURCE.MatTERA,SOURCE.MatTERC,SOURCE.StatutMat);
```

Comment: Why do you want the trigger to fire more than once?

Comment: Because for each row added in my table "ZZ"  I might need to add new ones in another table :)

Comment: And the merge is updating/inserted approx. 2000 rows

Comment: `inserted` is a virtual table that will contain more than one row if the statement causing the trigger to fire updated more than one row. Seeing the line `SELECT @NumeroOF = inserted.Ordre from inserted;`, you are not taking that fact into account. Not only that, but having a cursor in a trigger is a bad idea. Just glancing at what you are trying to do, it looks like this can be done in one SQL statement.

Comment: I guess I still don't see why the trigger needs to fire more than once. All the data should be in the `inserted` virtual table, and if you really need to go row by row over that, you can, within the trigger.

Comment: Yes I can do this, but I was wondering if there was a lazy way of simply telling my merge to execute the trigger multiple times so I don't have to modify it

Comment: So I should add another cursor which goes through my virtual inserted table?

Comment: It is NEVER appropriate to have a cursor in a trigger. Triggers need to operate on sets of data.   In fact you should never consider using a cursor at all until you know better when to use them. They are generally a last choice and almost never a first choice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so what's a better way to execute this trigger one time for all the entries in my virtual table `inserted`?

Comment: ALL triggers should ALWAYS be written assuming multiple rows in the inserted and/or deleted collection. NEVER assume just one row. You should use SET operations on the inserted/deleted virtual tables to do your work. Worst case, you can iterate over the rows, but that's last resort. NEVER use a cursor in a trigger. And no, there's no way to make a trigger get invoked once per row that's being inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: Thanks but why are cursor that bad?

Comment: Cursors are SLOW. Very, very slow. And you don't want triggers to ever be slow. Triggers need to be FAST.  "Set" operations are FAST, because that's what SQL Server is designed to do... operate on sets of rows, not go row-by-row iteratively. It should just be a rule that you never use a cursor in a trigger if it's at all avoidable... and it's almost always avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the cursor is incorrectly written to handle sets of data. Any trigger setting a value form inserted or deleted to a scalar variable is incorrect and for reasons of data integrity MUST be rewritten. This trigger is buggy. Period. There is no getting around that it must be rewritten (and any others that use the same technique).

The code inside your trigger should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin)
SELECT max(Id),l.Matricule,l.IdAction, 13,GETDATE(),1 
FROM Log l
JOIN Inserted i ON l.NumeroOF = i.Ordre
WHERE i.Statut LIKE '%CLOT%' OR i.Statut LIKE '%CLTT%' OR i.Statut LIKE '%CONF%'
GROUP BY l.Matricule,l.IdAction

INSERT INTO Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin)
SELECT max(Id),l.Matricule,l.IdAction, 2,GETDATE(),1 
FROM Log l
JOIN Inserted i ON l.NumeroOF = i.Ordre
WHERE IdAction<=2
WHERE i.Statut LIKE '%CLOT%' OR i.Statut LIKE '%CLTT%' OR i.Statut LIKE '%CONF%'
GROUP BY l.Matricule,l.IdAction
```

Make sure to test with both single record and multiple record inserts as all triggers should be tested. Then try your MERGE once  you are confident the trigger is correct.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me and don't worry I am on a testing server + I can rollback ;)